# ng-click work but $http does not work other function work fine

Tags: angularjs, spring

Here is my html code >

```
<a  ng-click="giftCategoriesProduct(x.categories_id)" >

    <img src="{{x.categories_image}}"
                                                                                  style="width: 100%; height: 40%" class="img-rectangle" />
        </a>
```

Here is my `angualarjs` code .

```
$scope.giftCategoriesProduct =  function (id) {
    alert('id'+id);
    $http({

        method : 'POST',
        url : '/KaroMiddle/fetchProductById'  
    }).success(function (response) {
        alert('inside success');
            $scope.products = response;


        }).error(function (error) {

            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;

        });


}
```

what happened don't understand please help me... other function work fine they are same like this function but `$http` and `success` does not work please suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Add the error handling function to see what does the call returns

Comment: Define "does not work". What do you expect to happen, precisely, and what happens instead, precisely?